# Android Intent with a p7s digital signature to sign email

Tags: android, email, android-intent, digital-signature, email-attachments

I am trying to send an Intent to be handled by a user selected email app. The Intent has a signature as an attachment. I read that the Gmail app cannot handle custom mime types so I tap on K-9 Mail to handle the intent instead.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"foo@bar.com"});
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email test");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, confirmEmailBody);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriSigned);
emailIntent.setType("application/pkcs7-signature");
try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Sending email..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I have uriSigned from a p7s file (present on the SD card), generated from the string confirmEmailBody. The intent above sets the attachment properties like this:

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-signature;
 name="smime.p7s"
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename="smime.p7s";
 size=1886
```

However, the attachment is not discovered as a signature because the general email Content-Type (located alongside sender info, time, etc.) is multipart/mixed when it should be multipart/signed.
How to set the header in the intent so it would end up as **Content-Type: multipart/signed;** in the email?

After it shows up as a signature I'll see if it will be validated against the body of the email.

P.S. Of course, I can easily send a correctly signed email using javamail but I want to avoid asking the user for the phone's gmail password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I didn't manage to find a way to make this work the way I want, I thought I'd post my alternative way to work around the problem, still avoiding asking for the password. I used Google Play Services to get Auth2 token.

```
String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, userEmail, "oauth2:https://mail.google.com/");
SMTPTransport smtpTransport = connectToSmtp("smtp.gmail.com", 587, userEmail, token, true);

SMTPMessage smtpMessage = new SMTPMessage(smtpSession);
smtpMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userEmail));
smtpMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
smtpMessage.setSubject(subject);
smtpMessage.setContent(multipart, multipart.getContentType());
smtpMessage.saveChanges();

smtpTransport.sendMessage(smtpMessage, smtpMessage.getAllRecipients());
smtpTransport.close();
```

Of course you can choose the oauth2 scope that suits your needs. To set SMTPTransport to accept the token (and create smtpSession for the code above):

```
private SMTPTransport connectToSmtp(String host, int port, String userEmail, String oauthToken, boolean debug) throws Exception {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.sasl.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.sasl.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
        props.put("mail.imaps.sasl.mechanisms.oauth2.oauthToken", oauthToken);
        smtpSession = Session.getInstance(props);
        smtpSession.setDebug(debug);

        final URLName unusedUrlName = null;
        SMTPTransport transport = new SMTPTransport(smtpSession, unusedUrlName);
        // If the password is non-null, SMTP tries to do AUTH LOGIN.
        final String emptyPassword = null;
        transport.connect(host, port, userEmail, emptyPassword);

        byte[] responseTemp = String.format("user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1", userEmail, oauthToken).getBytes();
        byte[] response = BASE64EncoderStream.encode(responseTemp);
        transport.issueCommand("AUTH XOAUTH2 " + new String(response), 235);

        return transport;
}
```

For more information, see these links: [Authorizing with Google on Android](http://developer.android.com/google/auth/http-auth.html), [OAuth2 info](https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol)